# Native linux installation on another drive, alongside Windows 7

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation

I have Windows 7 on my `C:` (primary) drive. Can I install another hard drive, and put Linux on it to ensure that there will be no conflicts?

Comment: Of course. You can choose your partition layout. (from "many OSs, one disc" to "one OS, many discs")

Comment: If you install Linux on a new hard drive, it is unlikely that windows will see that as `D:`. There will be no conflict through the install, but there might be if you decide to combine the booting process for Linux **and** Windows to start from your current drive. If you boot from floppy/USB/CD into Linux, there will be no conflicts for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, you just will have to be sure about the priorities of those disks - in the BIOS, simply which OS (from which disk) you want to boot at first, well then you even have an option of dual or booting more than 2 OSs in a single boot loader if you configure it.